# Create a list of names of those who answered a question correctly

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a finished Google Form connected to a Google Spreadsheet - I want to list the names of everyone who answered a specific question correctly. I've spent a while trying to figure out how to do this and have failed. I have one column (B) with their name and another column (H) with their answer. If they got it correct, I want to `=ARRAYFORMULA` anyone who got the question correct into a new list at `Statistics!A4`. How can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried, add some sample data and the expected result and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcome, Luke. You want to report on who _answered a specific question correctly_ I think a query or a Filter would do the trick. However, I can't be more specific without knowing the name of the sheet containing the responses, whether the answers to the question were numbers or strings (or both), **AND** what was the correct answer? Would you please edit your question to provide that information (together with the information requested by @Rubén).

Comment: Luke, you have specified that you answer should be an `arrayformula`. Would you please explain why. Have you tried to develop an answer using `QUERY` or `FILTER`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `filter()` formula to get the list, like this:

`=filter('Form Responses 1'!B2:B, 'Form Responses 1'!H2:H = "...put correct answer here...")`

To squeeze the list into the one cell `Statistics!A4`, wrap the `filter()` in a `textjoin()`, like this:

```
=textjoin( 
  ", ", 
  true, 
  iferror( 
    filter(
      'Form Responses 1'!B2:B, 
      'Form Responses 1'!H2:H = "...put correct answer here..." 
    ) 
  )
)
```